# How do i make a simple c++ program that prints all consecutive dates?

Tags: c++

I need help making a program that prints all consecutive dates.
My program has two functions

```
    void print_consecutive_days(int num, int delay_ms)
```

And

```
    bool is_leap_year(int year)
```

I am allowed to use any helper functions but cout can only be used in void print_consecutive_days
The program should print from

```
    6(0sun-6sat) 1(month) 1(day1-31ex) 2000(year)
```

The code should end with 7581 lines and should look like this

```
   6 1 1 2000
   ...
   5 10 2 2020
```

I have tried so many times to do this but i have not gotten close to figuring it out. I need this to be done as simply as possible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are the meaning of the `num` and `delay_ms` parameters in the `print_consecutive_days` signature?

Comment: Tables.  The remainder operator.  The easiest method is to have a 13 element array that contains the days of the month for each month.  The first entry, at index 0, should be 0 because months are indices 1 through 12, inclusive.  The leap year function determines whether February has 28 or 29 days.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints.

### Remainder operator for day of week

Let's base the program on incrementing by day.  Thus the numeric day of the week can be determined by using the remainder operator, `'%'`:

```
int day_of_week = day % 7;
```

### Months

Since months have varying lengths of days, a table is a good way to go:

```
static const int days_in_month[13] = 
{ // N/A, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
     0,   31,  28,  31,  30,  31,   30,  31,  30, 31,  30,  31
};

int month_num = 1;
if (day_count >= days_in_month[month_num])
{
   day_count -= days_in_month;
   ++month_num;
   if (day_count == 0) day_count += 1;
}
```

You can find the code for determining leap years by search the internet or StackOverflow for "c++ leap year".

Remember to use 29 days for February if the year is a leap year.

Also, check the month number, after incrementing, for overflowing past 12.  (if overflow, increment the year).

### Use A Debugger

I recommend writing a little bit of code, then running with a debugger.
After the code works, add more and repeat.